# Javascript. Как реализовать взаимодействие DOM-элементов?

Tags: javascript

К примеру у нас есть два div'a, которые изображены в виде шаров. Их задача перемещаться по экрану в любом направлении, и как только эти шары пересекаются, их цвет меняется на произвольные или они отталкиваются друг от друга, Неважно.
Меня интересует при помощи чего в JS можно реализовать такое поведение?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51978/discussion-on-question-by-denisoed-javascript----do).

Answer (score 2):

Зная размеры шаров и их координаты, каждый момент времени проверяете, пересекаются ли они (на самом деле достаточно проверять наступление момента, когда расстояние между их центрами меньше суммы их радиусов).